# index based on field date in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am importing a syslog using logstash (version 1.5.3) into elasticsearch(version 1.7.1) using the following configuration.

```
input{
  file {
    path => "somepath\*.log"
  }
}
filter{
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:message_hostname} %{DATA:message_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:message_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:user_message}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch{
    cluster => somecluster 
    host => localhost 
    index => "logindex-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
  }
}
```

My index is created based on the current date and time i.e. `logindex-2015-08-07`.

I want to create the index based on the date `syslog_timestamp` and not the current date using the above format `{+YYYY-MM-dd}`

So If the log had a timestamp `2015-01-01`, my index should be created as `logindex-2015-01-01` and not `logindex-2015-08-07`

**EDIT**

Log Input Used:

```
Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message
```

**Logstash Debug Output**

```
←[36mfilter received {:event=>{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]:(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"69", :method=>"filter_func"}
 ←[0m
 ←[36mRunning grok filter {:event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x166d6250 @metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x14fe0ed7 @store={}, @lut={}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT"}, @metadata={}, @accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x6ee8ffaf @store={"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT"}, @lut={"host"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root)
CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT"}, "host"]}>>, :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Folder/logstash-1.5.3/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-1.0.0/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb", :line=>"283", :method=>"filter"}
←[0m
←[36mRegexp match object {:names=>["SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:message_timestamp", "SYSLOGHOST:message_hostname", "DATA:message_program", "POSINT:message_pid", "GREEDYDATA:user_message"], :captures=>["Jul 27 07:49:01", "Server1", "CRON", "21009", "(root) CMD LTest Message\r"], :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Folder/logstash-1.5.3/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-grok-0.11.2/lib/grok-pure.rb", :line=>"179", :method=>"match_and_capture"}
←[0m
←[36mfilters/LogStash::Filters::Grok: adding value to field {:field=>"received_at", :value=>["%{@timestamp}"], :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Folder/logstash-1.5.3/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/util/decorators.rb", :line=>"28", :method=>"add_fields"}

←[0m
←[36mEvent now:  {:event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x166d6250 @metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x14fe0ed7 @store={}, @lut={}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, @metadata={}, @accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x6ee8ffaf @store={"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, @lut={"host"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "host"], "message"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009","user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message"], "message_timestamp"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_timestamp"], "message_hostname"=>[{"message"=>"Jul27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_hostname"], "message_program"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTestMessage\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_program"], "message_pid"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_pid"], "user_message"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "user_message"], "@timestamp"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "@timestamp"], "received_at"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01","message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "received_at"]}>>, :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Folder/logstash-1.5.3/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-1.0.0/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb", :line=>"303", :method=>"filter"}

←[0m
←[36mDate filter: received event {:type=>nil, :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Folder/logstash-1.5.3/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter
-date-1.0.0/lib/logstash/filters/date.rb", :line=>"206", :method=>"filter"}
←[0m←[36mDate filter looking for field {:type=>nil, :field=>"syslog_timestamp", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Folder/logstash-1.5.3/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/
jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-date-1.0.0/lib/logstash/filters/date.rb", :line=>
"209", :method=>"filter"}
←[0m
←[36moutput received {:event=>{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]:(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"76", :method=>"output_func"}
←[0m
←[36mFlushing output {:outgoing_count=>1, :time_since_last_flush=>22.048, :outgoing_events=>{nil=>[["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"%index-2015-08-14", :_type=>"logs", :_routing=>nil},
#<LogStash::Event:0x166d6250 
@metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x14fe0ed7 @store={"retry_count"=>0}, @lut={}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, @metadata={"retry_count"=>0}, 
@accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x6ee8ffaf @store={"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, @lut={"host"=>[{"message"=>sage\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, @lut={"host"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r","received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "host"], "message"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message"], "message_timestamp"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_timestamp"], "message_hostname"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_hostname"], "message_program"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_program"], "message_pid"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "message_pid"], "user_message"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "user_message"], "@timestamp"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 2707:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "@timestamp"], "received_at"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "received_at"], "type"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r","received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "type"], "syslog_timestamp"=>[{"message"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z", "host"=>"HOST-LT", "message_timestamp"=>"Jul 27 07:49:01", "message_hostname"=>"Server1", "message_program"=>"CRON", "message_pid"=>"21009", "user_message"=>"(root) CMD LTest Message\r", "received_at"=>"2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"}, "syslog_timestamp"]}>>]]}, :batch_timeout=>1, :force=>nil, :final=>nil, :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Folder/logstash-1.5.3/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.20/lib/stud/buffer.rb", :line=>"207", :method=>"buffer_flush"}

←[0m{              "message" => "Jul 27 07:49:01 Server1 CRON[21009]: (root) CMD LTest Message\r",
             "@version" => "1",
           "@timestamp" => "2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z",
                 "host" => "HOST-LT",
    "message_timestamp" => "Jul 27 07:49:01",
     "message_hostname" => "Server1",
      "message_program" => "CRON",
          "message_pid" => "21009",
         "user_message" => "(root) CMD LTest Message\r",
          "received_at" => "2015-08-14T07:34:53.215Z"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that the locale on your machine is different from the locale used to produce the log. So you should specify the `locale` in your `date` filter, like this:

```
...
filter{
    grok {
        ...
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      locale => "en"
    }
}
...
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your log output above (very helpful!!), your `date` filter should work on the `message_timestamp` field and not `syslog_timestamp` (which doesn't exist)

Comment: The `date` field is coming out correct. The issue is that I want my ES index (`index => "logindex-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"`) to be created based on the `syslog_timestamp` with format `YYYY-MM-dd` and not the current system date

Comment: Weird, as that's what the `date` filter does by default, i.e. it copies the matched date to the `@timestamp` field. How does your `@timestamp` field look like?

Comment: In ES, `@timestamp` comes out as the current date.Like `"@timestamp": "2015-08-14T06:28:02.018Z"` for a log inserted today even though the log is of July 27th. Not sure if this adds any benefit but I have this  `add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]` in grok which I omitted as it just adds another field from  `@timestamp`.

Comment: Oh, and what version of Logstash are you using?

Comment: version 1.5.3 for Logstash

Comment: I suggest you run logstash with `--debug`  and then paste the output for a single log line in your question. That way we'll see what the date filter gets and what it does with it.

Comment: Updated question with debug output for date filter

Comment: I would add the lines before (`filter received`, `Running grok filter`, `Regexp match object `, ...) and the lines after (`Date parsing done`, ...)  as well. And also the lines for the `elasticsearch` output.

Comment: Have you changed the logstash config? I see `SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:message_timestamp` instead of `SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp`, i.e. not the same field as the one used by your `date` filter.

Comment: youre right. the fields were incorrect!!! Once I changed the fields in my sandbox environment, it worked. Even more amazing thing is that this was based on an original config on the live env with ifs and other conditions which had the fields mapped perfectly in grok and date where it initially didn't work.

Comment: Glad I could help sort it out!